# Java : cannot get String value by Apache dbutils

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-dbutils

Here is a test program I wrote with Apache dbutils :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bacula";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "bacula";
        String pwd = "root";
        try {
            DbUtils.loadDriver(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
            QueryRunner query = new QueryRunner();

            List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = query.query(conn, "select * from Client", new MapListHandler());

            for (Iterator<Map<String, Object>> li = mapList.iterator(); li.hasNext();) {
                Map<String, Object> m = li.next();  
                for (Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> mi = m.entrySet().iterator(); mi.hasNext();) {  
                    Entry<String, Object> e = mi.next();  
                    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue());  
                }  
            }  
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is :

```
ClientId=1
Name=[B@8146158
Uname=[B@7202dc8c
AutoPrune=1
FileRetention=2592000
JobRetention=15552000
```

But Name and Uname should be of type "string" in MySQL, where did I make an error ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String s = new String(bytes);` . The representation is of `byte[]` that's returned from the select query.

In your program, it would be like,

```
String key = e.getKey();
String value = e.getValue();
if(key.equals("Name") || key.equals("UName")){
    System.out.println(key + "=" + new String((byte[])value));
}else{
   System.out.println(key  + "=" + value );
}
```

I might have typos. But try this one. Looks like you are getting byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Check this page to know to the mapping between SQL types and java type

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html